# How to set default values to NO for "links can be purchased separately" for Downloadble Products in magento

Tags: magento

Hi guy i have a magento site my products is downloadable, in adding a new product, there have a 'Downloadable Information' Tab, in the accordion in the 'Link' there have a field "links can be purchased separately"

How to set default values to NO?

thanks...

Answer (score -1):

I think you can find the attribute_code "links_purchased_separately" in the **eav_attribute** table here you can try setting the default value to 0 (zero) means No.

Comment: thank for the answer. i try but, it still 'Links can be purchased  - Yes'.